# Adding control from the Source and generate it in the designer.vb?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The problem that I'm having is that the design of an .aspx has a lot of controls that a lot of things are collapsed and pretty much impossible to visual the page as it should be from the Visual Studio.

Because of that, I can't add like a `CheckBoxList` from the toolbox directly to the Design window next to a `<label>` for example.

So I have to work from the Source and add that `CheckBoxList` from there, let's say inside a `<tr>` and next to a `<td>` with a `<label>`.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

One question I have is, why doesn't the designer.vb auto-generate (add) the `CheckBoxList` control unless I specify an ID to it?

After I add that control from the source, is it possible to open up the Property Window (since I wouldn't be able to find/rightclick from the Design window? And also how can I create an event for that control?

Is it possible to reorganize that .aspx design and basically rearrange everything 
and make it look like when I visualize it from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reorganize that .aspx design and basically rearrange
>   everything and make it look like when I visualize it from the browser?

It seems like you come from *WinForms* background. Web Form Designer window won't normally match up with what we see inside a browser. So, we - web developers - do not use Designer.

Changing a markup while debugging doesn't need to recompile the application, so we just press F5 to refresh the browser. My suggestion will be not to use Designer at all, because there is no Designer Window in ASP.NET MVC.

***FYI***: I use Resharper which displays [intelligence for events](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/asp_net_editor.html), when I partially type event name inside the source. Then when I press enter, it automatically creates the event in Code Behind file.